# centos 7: rsh permission denied when used with a command

Tags: centos7, rsh

When I use rexec to a server, it work's but rsh does not. Any idea what could be wrong?

Using rexec

```
$ rexec 10.60.114.192 echo hi
Password: 
hi
```

Using rsh

```
$ rsh 10.60.114.192 echo hi
Permission denied.
```

I've followed https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/setup-remote-shell-access-rsh-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html

rhosts.equiv

```
# cat /etc/rhosts.equiv 
+ +
```

securetty

```
# cat /etc/securetty 
rsh
rexec
rlogin
```

UPDATE:
oddly, I can log in via rsh

```
$ rsh 10.60.114.192 
Password: 
Last login: Mon Apr 23 06:11:04 on pts/0
```

Comment: long time since you asked but today I ran into the same kind of problem. Turns out the user with the problem had her .rhosts file set to rwx. Apparently redhat (maybe centos) checks and it must be r-- (644). Hope that helps.